# How to read file in compilation time using Java?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a project which consists of reading 1000 XML files, each defining a rule of processing the different types of data. The consequence is that the application takes a few seconds to load the XML files when it starts. It's an Android mobile app so the CPU isn't very powerful.

Is there a way to create static objects at compilation time by reading these XML files? If I can pre-process the XML by defining static objects which already have the XML read into it, the app should be able to start loaded, a lot faster. The draw-back that the XML file can't change in the runtime is acceptable.

This is a generic question - I am not bound to use any specific method or library. Anything that allows me to pre-parse the XML will do. But as comments asked for my current runtime-parsing implementation, I provide it in the following paragraphs which uses the DOM parser shipped with Java.

---

The current implementation:

The XML processing class simply creates an object by reads each XML file. It is used like this:

```
lst.add(XMLData(new FileInputStream(new File("assets/001.xml"))));
lst.add(XMLData(new FileInputStream(new File("assets/002.xml"))));
....
```

Where XMLData is the object that reads the XML file and keeps the relevant information. `lst` is a `List` of such objects.

The XMLData class look like this:

```
class XMLDAta {
  public XMLData(InputStream xml) throws IOException, SAXException {
   DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO: if schema has problems (e.g. defined twice).
        // all XML well-formedness were checked before shipping them
        e.printStackTrace();  // shouldn't happen
        return;
    }
    Document xml = dBuilder.parse(xmlAsset);
```

Comment: You may need to write your own parser. There are frameworks like JAXB that generate POJOs which can be marshaled from xml, but the marshaling is during run-time so that's not what you want.

Comment: What is the structure of the classes that read the xml or where does the data contained in the xml end up in the program?

Comment: Comments answered by changing the question text:)